# Increasing and bijective function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> $f$ is a function: $E \to F$ such that for any $a \in E \, and \,  b \in E$, we have the property:
> $a < b$ if and only if $f(a) < f(b)$

What is characteristics of such function f ? Prove it.

I think that $f$ should be a bijective increasing function but I'm not sure whether such condition is too strong or not. Moreover, if it is such a case, how to prove the part: if $f(a) < f(b)$ then $a < b$ ?

Comment: $f$ may not be bijective.

Comment: @Gae.S.: could you give further explanation please ? It would be nice if you could spend some time to answer the question, it is very kind of you! Thank you very much!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge Think about it: Does $f$ need to hit every point of $F$?

Comment: $f$ is a monotonically strictly increasing function. This implies that $f$ is also injective. But it may not be surjective. Anyways, if you change the range of $f$ to $f(E)$, then that function is also surjective, and for almost all real analysis purposes has the same properties as $f$. But is still not $f$!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the characteristics of such function $f$?

This kind of function is called a monotonically increasing function. These functions are automatically injective. Not necessarily they are bijective. Think about a simple example: $\mathbb{A}=[1, 2]$ and function $f$ from $\mathbb{A}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ that maps $x$ into $x^2.$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ must be injective, since if we have $x \neq y$, this means one is strictly larger than the other, and so one of their images under $f$ is also strictly larger than the other, so $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

However it does not need to be surjective, for example $f = arctan$.